# Chrome driver is not able to pickup a file from the system when we run it through a Service

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

When I run Selenium Grid (Hub and Node) through a windows service and try to get a file from my system in my test cases through chrome driver, it shows "File not found on the path" at the sendkeys function of Selenium Webdriver, also if I do a File.Exist in the service the file is available and when I run it normally without service it is able to pick up the file with the same code. 
Note: When we run test cases through service Web page and chrome is not visible and when we run normally web page and chrome is visible.

I am using Selenium Webdriver with C#.

```
public void FileUpload(IWebDriver driver,string pathOfFolder, string attachmentFile)
{                
    var filePath = Path.Combine(pathOfFolder, attachmentFile); 

    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='file']")).SendKeys(filePath);
    }      

}
```

File is picked up from a shared drive(T:):
filepath = "T:\SampleFolder\FileUpload.xlsx";
The shared drive and the service have all the required permissions(I have used administrator permissions).

The problem arises when I do sendKeys with the path it gives file not found exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium driver not able to pick file from system when we run it through a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150455/selenium-driver-not-able-to-pick-file-from-system-when-we-run-it-through-a-servi)

Comment: @DebanjanB That question was not proper, so rewrote the whole question.